# Grouping time and counting instances by 12 hour bins in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df1 like this :

```
    timestamp
01-12-2015 00:04
01-12-2015 02:20
01-12-2015 02:43
01-12-2015 04:31
01-12-2015 08:51
01-12-2015 11:28
01-12-2015 20:53
01-12-2015 21:28
02-12-2015 00:30
02-12-2015 20:22
```

Which contains time stamps. I would want to get count by binning hours in 12 hours interval i.e(01-12-2015[0-9],01-12-2015[9-21], and so on.

output Sample:

```
DayOfMonth Group count
    1   1   5
    1   2   2
    2   1   2
    2   2   1
```

The day of month can be replaced by Serial Number also, starting with 1. Any help to solve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: We can use `cut` after converting to `Date`

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying with cut function but not able to get the desired output.

Comment: No problem . I posted it as solution.

Comment: Ehm... [0-9] - [9-21] is just 9 hours interval, not 12... am I not getting something ?

Comment: Sure, [21-0] is previous day is combined with [0-9] of next day

Comment: @warwick12: ok then, edited my question accordingly ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution in base R:

```
# convert the 'timestamp' column to a datetime format
df1$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df1$timestamp, format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'))
# create day.of.month variable
df1$day.of.month <- format(df1$timestamp, '%d')
# extract the 12 hour interval as am/pm values
df1$group <- gsub('[0-9: ]+','\\1',format(df1$timestamp, '%r'))
# aggregate
aggregate(. ~ group + day.of.month, df1, length)
```

which gives:

```
  group day.of.month timestamp
1    am           01         6
2    pm           01         2
3    am           02         1
4    pm           02         1
```

Another solution using `data.table` and and the `pm` function of `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, timestamp := dmy_hm(timestamp)
           ][, group := pm(timestamp)+1
             ][, .N, .(day.of.month = day(timestamp),group)]
```

which gives:

```
   day.of.month group N
1:            1     1 6
2:            1     2 2
3:            2     1 1
4:            2     2 1
```

---

Used data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(timestamp = c("01-12-2015 00:04", "01-12-2015 02:20", "01-12-2015 02:43", "01-12-2015 04:31", "01-12-2015 08:51", 
                                    "01-12-2015 11:28", "01-12-2015 20:53", "01-12-2015 21:28", "02-12-2015 00:30", "02-12-2015 20:22")),
                 .Names = "timestamp", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well but it's summing up the count if I've multiple months data. For that I'm adding df1$month as a variable.

Comment: @warwick12 you could use either `month(df1$timestamp)` (`data.table`/`lubridate`) of `format(df1$timestamp, '%m')` (base R) to create a month variable

Answer (score 2):

We can use `lubridate` functions to convert to 'Datetime' class easily and with `dplyr` to get the output efficiently compared to `base R` methods.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(timestamp = dmy_hm(timestamp)) %>%
    group_by(DayOfMonth = day(timestamp)) %>%
    group_by(Group = as.numeric(cut(timestamp, breaks = "12 hour")), 
            add=TRUE)  %>% 
    summarise(GroupCount = n())
#     DayOfMonth Group GroupCount
#         <int> <dbl>      <int>
#1          1     1          6
#2          1     2          2
#3          2     1          1
#4          2     2          1
```

---

Or we can use a compact option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, {t1 <- dmy_hm(timestamp); .(DayOfMonth = day(t1), 
   Group = (hour(t1)>12)+1L)}][, .(GroupCount = .N), .(DayOfMonth, Group)]
#     DayOfMonth Group GroupCount
#1:          1     1          6
#2:          1     2          2
#3:          2     1          1
#4:          2     2          1
```

NOTE: The `data.table` solution is done with just two steps...

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(timestamp = c("01-12-2015 00:04", "01-12-2015 02:20", 
"01-12-2015 02:43", "01-12-2015 04:31", "01-12-2015 08:51", "01-12-2015 11:28", 
"01-12-2015 20:53", "01-12-2015 21:28", "02-12-2015 00:30", "02-12-2015 20:22"
)), .Names = "timestamp", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error:Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('POSIXct', 'POSIXt')". Shall I change the timestamp format?

Comment: Thanks, I think the issue is with timestamp format. I'm still getting the error: all formats failed to parse

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution in base R :

```
timeStamp <- c("01-12-2015 00:04","01-12-2015 02:20","01-12-2015 02:43","01-12-2015 04:31",
               "01-12-2015 08:51","01-12-2015 11:28","01-12-2015 20:53","01-12-2015 21:28",
               "02-12-2015 00:30","02-12-2015 20:22")
times <- as.POSIXlt(timeStamp,format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M",tz='GMT')

DF <- data.frame(Times=times)
DF$Group <- as.logical(times$hour > 12) + 1
DF$DayOfMonth <- times$mday

res <- aggregate(Times ~ DayOfMonth + Group,data=DF, FUN = length)

# res :
#   DayOfMonth Group Times
# 1          1     1     6
# 2          2     1     1
# 3          1     2     2
# 4          2     2     1
```

Or if you want to include dates in hours range: [21-0] of previous day in the next day :

```
timeStamp <- c("01-12-2015 00:04","01-12-2015 02:20","01-12-2015 02:43","01-12-2015 04:31",
               "01-12-2015 08:51","01-12-2015 11:28","01-12-2015 20:53","01-12-2015 21:28",
               "02-12-2015 00:30","02-12-2015 20:22")
times <- as.POSIXlt(timeStamp,format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M",tz='GMT')
h <- times$hour + times$min*1/60 + times$sec*1/3600
# here we add 3 hours to the dates in hours range [21-0] in this way we
# push them to the next day
times[h >= 21] <- times[h >= 21] + 3*3600

DF <- data.frame(Times=times)
DF$Group <- ifelse(h < 9,1,ifelse(h <= 21,2,NA))
DF$DayOfMonth <- times$mday

res <- aggregate(Times ~ DayOfMonth + Group,data=na.omit(DF), FUN = length)

# res :
#   DayOfMonth Group Times
# 1          1     1     5
# 2          2     1     2
# 3          1     2     2
# 4          2     2     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the several already presented options, the `stringi` package has some date parsing functions as well:

```
library(stringi)
df1$timestamp <- stri_datetime_parse(df1$timestamp, format = 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm')
df1$DayOfMonth <- stri_datetime_format(df1$timestamp, format = 'd')
df1$Group <- stri_datetime_format(df1$timestamp, format = 'a')
```

After that you can get a count with for example the following two options:

```
# option 1:
aggregate(. ~ Group + DayOfMonth, df1, length) # copied from @ProcrastinatusMaximus

# option 2a:
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(DayOfMonth, Group) %>% 
  tally()

# option 2b:
count(df1, DayOfMonth, Group)
```

The output of the latter:

```
  DayOfMonth Group     n
       (chr) (chr) (int)
1          1  a.m.     6
2          1  p.m.     2
3          2  a.m.     1
4          2  p.m.     1
```